# All my operators work as an add operator in my calculator

Tags: javascript

So basically when I want to subtract, it adds numbers. When I wrote the same code for multiply and divide, it did the same thing. Instead of dividing, it was adding numbers etc. I have no idea why it's happening. It's like my javascript ignores dataset.action and treats operators like one button. If I put parseInt(num1) - parseInt(num2), then all operators subtract numbers.

```js
const calcDisplay = document.querySelector('.output');
calcDisplay.textContent = '0'

let num2 = ''

const add = (a, b) =>  a + b;
const subtract = (a, b) =>  a - b;
const multiply = (a, b) =>  a * b;
const divide = (a, b) => a / b;

//assigning calculator functions to operators' buttons //
  const buttonOperation = document.querySelectorAll('.keyButtonOperation').forEach(operator => {
    operator.addEventListener('click', () => {
      operator.classList.add('isDepressed');
      operator = operator.dataset.action;
      num2 = calcDisplay.textContent;
      if (operator === 'add') {
        return add;
      } if (operator === 'subtract') {
        return subtract;
      }
    
    
    
  });
  }) 


 //an event that make digits appear on the display // 
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.keyButton').forEach(button => {
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  removeClass();
  num1 = button.textContent;
  displayedNum = calcDisplay.textContent;

    if (displayedNum === '0') {
      calcDisplay.textContent = num1;
  } else if (displayedNum === num2) {
      calcDisplay.textContent = num1
  } else  {
      calcDisplay.textContent = displayedNum + num1
  }
  
  });

});


const buttonEquals = document.querySelector('.keyButtonEquals');
buttonEquals.addEventListener('click', () => {
  num1 = calcDisplay.textContent;
  document.querySelectorAll('.keyButtonOperation').forEach(operator => {
  operator = operator.dataset.action
    if(operator === 'add') {
      calcDisplay.textContent = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
    } else if (operator === 'subtract') {
      calcDisplay.textContent = parseInt(num1) - parseInt(num2)
    }

  }); 
  });

   
  






// Clears the whole display with one click //
const buttonClear = document.querySelector('.keyButtonClear');
buttonClear.addEventListener('click', () => {
  calcDisplay.textContent = '0'
  // I will fill up the rest of the code here when I get done with the rest //
  
});

// Deletes a single number when you click a button //
function deleteInput() {
  const deleteButton = document.querySelector('.keyButtonDelete')
  deleteButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    calcDisplay.textContent = calcDisplay.textContent.slice(0, -1);

  });
}
deleteInput()

//removes a selection of a operator after a second number is clicked //
function removeClass () {
  buttonRemove = document.querySelectorAll('.keyButtonOperation').forEach(button => {
  button.classList.remove('isDepressed')

  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Calculator</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/style.css">
        <body>
          <div class="calcContainer">

            
            <div class="buttons">
              <div class="output">
              </div>
              <button class="keyButton">7</button>
              <button class="keyButton">8</button>
              <button class="keyButton">9</button>
              <button class="keyButtonOperation" data-action = "SignChange" >+/-</button>
              <button class="keyButtonDelete">DEL</button>

              <button class="keyButton">4</button>
              <button class="keyButton">5</button>
              <button class="keyButton">6</button>
              <button class="keyButtonOperation" data-action="multiply">X</button>
              <button class="keyButtonOperation" data-action="divide">%</button>

              <button class="keyButton">1</button>
              <button class="keyButton">2</button>
              <button class="keyButton">3</button>
              <button class="keyButtonOperation" data-action = "subtract">-</button>
              <button class="keyButtonEquals" id="dupa">=</button>

              <button class="keyButtonClear">C</button>
              <button class="keyButton">0</button>
              <button class="keyButton">.</button>
              <button class="keyButtonOperation" data-action = "add">+</button>
            </div>
          </div>

            <script src="./scripts/script.js"></script>
        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It definitly needs to be cleaned up and probably should be remade where all operations/num presses are stored in a array to then be able to have more complex operations,.

The main idea here is to have a `num1` and `num2` variable that gets set to the first and second arguments of the operation, the operation type is stored in `oper` then when the user presses `=` is switch is triggered and does the operation

```js
const calcDisplay = document.querySelector('.output');
calcDisplay.textContent = '0'
let total = 0 // ADDED new variable to store total
let oper = '' // have an operation variable to know what to do when = is pressed
let num1 = ''
let num2 = ''
      
//an event that make digits appear on the display // 
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.keyButton').forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (calcDisplay.textContent == '0' || (num2 == '' && oper != '')){
        calcDisplay.textContent = ''
    }
    if (oper == '' || num1 != ''){   //to allow for bigger then 9 numbers
        calcDisplay.textContent += button.textContent;
    }else{
        calcDisplay.textContent = button.textContent;
    }
        
    if (num1 == '' || oper == '') {
        num1 = calcDisplay.textContent; 
    } else {
        num2 = calcDisplay.textContent; 
    } 
    
    });

   });

      document.querySelectorAll('.keyButtonOperation').forEach(operator => {
          operator.addEventListener('click', () => {
          oper = operator.dataset.action
      });
      });
      const equalButton = document.querySelector('.keyButtonEquals')
          equalButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
          switch (oper){
            case 'add':
                total = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
                break;
            case 'subtract':
                total = parseInt(num1) - parseInt(num2);
                break;
            case 'multiply':
                total = parseInt(num1) * parseInt(num2);
                break;
            case 'divide':
                total = parseInt(num1) / parseInt(num2);
                break;
          }
          calcDisplay.textContent = total;
          oper = ''
          num2 = '';
          num1 = total;
        });

      // Clears the whole display with one click //
      //const buttonClear = document.querySelector('.keyButtonClear');
      //buttonClear.addEventListener('click', () => {
        //calcDisplay.textContent = '0'
        // I will fill up the rest of the code here when I get done with the rest //

      //});

      // Deletes a single number when you click a button //
      function deleteInput() {
        const deleteButton = document.querySelector('.keyButtonDelete')
        deleteButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
          calcDisplay.textContent = calcDisplay.textContent.slice(0, -1);

        });
      }
      deleteInput()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Calculator</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/style.css">
        <body>
          <div class="calcContainer">

            
            <div class="buttons">
              <div class="output">
              </div>
              <button class="keyButton">7</button>
              <button class="keyButton">8</button>
              <button class="keyButton">9</button>
              <button class="keyButtonOperation" data-action = "SignChange" >+/-</button>
              <button class="keyButtonDelete">DEL</button>

              <button class="keyButton">4</button>
              <button class="keyButton">5</button>
              <button class="keyButton">6</button>
              <button class="keyButtonOperation" data-action="multiply">X</button>
              <button class="keyButtonOperation" data-action="divide">%</button>

              <button class="keyButton">1</button>
              <button class="keyButton">2</button>
              <button class="keyButton">3</button>
              <button class="keyButtonOperation" data-action = "subtract">-</button>
              <button class="keyButtonEquals" id="dupa">=</button>

              <button class="keyButtonClear">C</button>
              <button class="keyButton">0</button>
              <button class="keyButton">.</button>
              <button class="keyButtonOperation" data-action = "add">+</button>
            </div>
          </div>

            <script src="./scripts/script.js"></script>
        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple logic flaws and inconsistencies,

the problem responsible for the constant adding is the fact that the variable operator that you use to check what button has been pressed(ei: `if(operator === 'add')..`) is being defined as all your operator.

`document.querySelectorAll('.keyButtonOperation').forEach(operator => {` just iterates through the different buttons, add is the lastt button and thus it's always triggered, the fix would depend on your goal, are you looking for multiple chained operations (`3+4*2/6`) or just one operation (`9/3`) if you want multiple you'll need to deal with oders of operation.

Your also setting onclicks to functions that require inputs and don't have clear outputs
`const add = (`**a, b**`) =>`  **a + b**`;` JS can't guess what `a` and `b` corespond to, or set the output text if you don't tell it how.

Comment: I just want simple operation.  when it comes to const add, should I change it to num1 and num2 instead of a + b? and why is add the last  button? I created operator = operator.dataset.action so javascript knows what button is clicked, then I assigned functions like add and subract to it.

Comment: because your looping through your buttons for example your add button's action is "add" (data-action = "add"), it doesn't contain info on when it was added, I sugest you remove the `document.querySelectorAll('.keyButtonOperation').forEach(operator => {` that's nested within the buttonEquals one.